# how to select an item from a list , display the selected item in the editText then from the edit text display it in a toast

Tags: android, android-intent, listactivity

i am creating a simple android application consist from 3 activities.

- Main Activity
- Second Activity
- List Page

the first activity has a button that display the listPage  using the **intent** 
after the user select an item from the list and click ok the system will transfer him to the **second Activity** that contain a edit box that the selected item will be display in it.
and after the user click get back message button the system will transfer him to the **MainActivity** and display the selected item in a **Toast** .

can anyone help me  to accomplish this tasks????

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.intentmenudemoapp;

import android.R.color;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView txt1, txt2;
    EditText edittxt1, edittxt2;
    Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;

    String msgStr, msgStr2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);

        edittxt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);

        edittxt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);

        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);

        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);

        registerForContextMenu(edittxt1);
        registerForContextMenu(edittxt2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        msgStr = edittxt1.getText().toString();

        msgStr2 = edittxt2.getText().toString();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.bold_item:

            edittxt1.setText(beautify(msgStr, "BOLD"));

            edittxt2.setText(beautify(msgStr2, "BOLD"));
            break;
        case R.id.italic_item:
            edittxt1.setText(beautify(msgStr, "ITALIC"));
            edittxt2.setText(beautify(msgStr2, "ITALIC"));
            break;

        case R.id.red_item:
            edittxt1.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.RED); // red
            edittxt2.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.RED); // red
            break;
        case R.id.blue_item:
            edittxt1.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.BLUE); // blue
            edittxt2.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.BLUE); // blue
            break;
        case R.id.yellow_item:
            edittxt1.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.YELLOW); // yellow
            edittxt2.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.YELLOW); // yellow
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        msgStr = edittxt1.getText().toString();
        msgStr2 = edittxt2.getText().toString();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.bold_item:
            edittxt1.setText(beautify(msgStr, "BOLD"));
            edittxt2.setText(beautify(msgStr2, "BOLD"));
            break;
        case R.id.italic_item:
            edittxt1.setText(beautify(msgStr, "ITALIC"));
            edittxt2.setText(beautify(msgStr2, "ITALIC"));

            break;
        case R.id.red_item:
            edittxt1.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.RED); // red
            edittxt2.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.RED); // red
            break;
        case R.id.blue_item:
            edittxt1.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.BLUE); // blue
            edittxt2.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.BLUE); // blue
            break;
        case R.id.yellow_item:
            edittxt1.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.YELLOW); // yellow
            edittxt2.setTextColor(color.background_dark | Color.YELLOW); // yellow
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private CharSequence beautify(String originalText, String selectedStyle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Spanned answer = null;
        if (selectedStyle.equals("BOLD"))
            answer = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + originalText + "</b>");
        else if (selectedStyle.equals("ITALIC"))
            answer = Html.fromHtml("<i>" + originalText + "</i>");
        else if (selectedStyle.equals("NORMAL"))
            answer = Html.fromHtml("<normal>" + originalText + "</normal>");

        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String value;

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn:

            value = edittxt1.getText().toString();
            txt2.setText(value);

            break;

        case R.id.btn2:
        //  value = edittxt1.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ListPage.class);
            //i.putExtra("msgFromFirstActivity", value);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            Intent ii = new Intent();
            ii.setType("image/pictures/*");
            ii.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivity(ii);
            break;
        case R.id.btn4:
            // get back message from second activity
            Intent iii = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(iii, 1);

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (null != data) {
                String returnMSG = data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");

                Toast.makeText(this, returnMSG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

## SecondActivity.java

```
/*get back the result from the list page and display it in the edit
 text box then after clicking show the result in the first activity as
 toast
 */

package com.devleb.intentmenudemoapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txt;
    EditText edittxt;
    String result;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
/*
        Intent iList = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(iList, 1);
    */
        edittxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_txt);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                result = edittxt.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("MESSAGE", result);

                setResult(1, i);

                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (null != data) {
                String returnMSG = data
                        .getStringExtra("MessageFromsecondActivity");

                // Toast.makeText(this, returnMSG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                edittxt.setText(returnMSG);
            } else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

*/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

## ListPage.java

```
package com.devleb.intentmenudemoapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListPage extends ListActivity {

    TextView txt;
    private static final String[] items = { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4",
            "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9" };
    Button btn;
    String result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_list);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_list);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
/*
                result = txt.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("MessageFromsecondActivity", result);
                setResult(1, i);

                finish();
*/
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        txt.setText(items[position]);
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

until now this what i did from here how to continue or what i need to add and change to make my tasks

Answer (score 0):

What here you can do is,
To pass data from first activity to second activity

```
Intent in = new Intent(Youractivity.this, secondactivity.class);
in.putExtra("value", valuetopass);
startActivity(in);
```

Now, get data in second activity

```
Intent in = getIntent();
String valuetoset = in.getStringExtra("value");
```

And then set this value to edittext

```
youredittext.setText(valuetoset);
```

Comment: @ Anil Bhatiya  from the listPage activity to the second activity i need to pass the selected value .. than in the second activity the selected value must be display in the edit box  then after i click on the button this selected value must be display in a Toast in the MainActivity .... your answer will solve this taks??

Comment: yes, but for that first u have to get the value from listpage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**ListPage.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
        String val = ((TextView) v).getText().toString().trim();
        txt.setText(items[position]);          
        Intent i = new Intent(ListPage.this, SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("value", val);
        startActivity(in);  
    }
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
       Intent i = getIntent();
       String val = "";

       if(i.hasExtra("value"))
             val = i.getStringExtra("value");

    edittxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_txt);
    edittxt.setText(val);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            result = edittxt.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("MESSAGE", result);
            startActivity(in); 
        }
    });
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
       String value = "";

       if(i.hasExtra("MESSAGE")){
             value = i.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```